# Is there some trick to block the Netflix "BangBang" sound?

Tags: audio, netflix

That horrible sound that hurts my ears, on the start of every episode with Netflix logo...

I would even root my phone if that sound could be detected, filtered and blocked...

May be some app that when there is no sound playing for 10s, auto lowers the volume to a minimum?

I use headphone always - I need to - but that just worsens the problem...

These big companies and their lack of config options are quite annoying...

Comment: Hey bud! I don't think there are such kind of apps. This is a very very specific issue. One quick thing you can do is writing to Netflix. They might take it as user feedback and implement something that might ease your issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the audio video clip of Netflix that shows up is not part of videos shown to users? If they are a part, even Netflix can't give an option to disable it. All it can do is to skip right to the time where the sound ends. I don't think we users can do anything given that the app is proprietary. One could try using a hack where some app reads up that Netflix is going Full screen, read the position of time slider, and if it is to the left extreme, then click X coordinates right to it so that bang bang sound is skipped. I don't think this would be smooth in implementation.

Comment: A fade in sound effect, everytime a sound begins playing, lasting 5s could work too. I will try to talk to netflix but i got used to not have much hope... An auto skip the initial 5s would be great too! May be some android app that macro record and plays screen tap events!

Answer (score 0):

This is a manual (non automatic) workaround.

I installed this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alwaysvolumebutton

It is highly configurable. I can move the buttons, rotate them, and make them transparent. And the volume percent shows on the button.

So with 1 click, i can quickly mute sounds and not show the bright annoying system volume control. To mute is a initially disabled option.

So, b4 clicking on play, i hit the mute button, and again after the bangbang, and that is very simple to use.

It may be buggy to configure, but as soon you manage to, it works fine.